# How can I move a superscript dfrac down within mathmode?

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math

I want to include some probabilities within a report, my PhD is not in maths so I do not need or desire to expand the probability density equation integral out but would like to show it with the calculated mean (`mu`) and standard deviation (`sigma`). I have calculated the values with the Python package [`scipy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/integrate.html) and MATLAB and I am compiling the document with `lualatex`. How it currently looks:

[image]

I am having to use `dfrac` for the exponent fractions as the normal `frac` is unreadable at just default zoom in my PDF reader:

[image]

How can I move the exponent down a little or reduce the font size a little for the `frac` components so that the minus sign doesn't look so comically high? I am conscious about not having the denominator in-line with the `dx` but it looks "ugly" right now. I am pretty inexperienced with math mode, I have looked for a solution but would appreciate a link if it is a duplicate, answers using `\DeclareMathSizes{x}{x}{x}{x}` had no effect in my document so I am assuming the `unicode-math` package is at work in someway.

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\setmainfont{Arial}[ItalicFont=ariali.ttf,
            BoldFont=arialbd.ttf,
            BoldItalicFont=arialbi.ttf]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\mbfitP(M_p \leq 2) = \int_0^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\dfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\;\mathrm{d}x
= \int_0^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(0.479)^2}}e^{-\dfrac{(x-1.517)^2}{2(0.479)^2}}\;\mathrm{d}x
\approx 0.843
\end{equation}
where $M_p$ is the MolProbity score, $\mu$ is the mean MolProbity score, $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the MolProbity score and all other symbols have their usual meanings.
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe a different notation will suite you better.

Comment: why are you using `\dfrac` in a superscript????

Comment: you are forcing the largest font, most spaced, **d**isplay **frac**tion,in a supercript that would normally have a smaller than standard size font

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I wanted to show it without `exp()` but I am guessing this is the wrong approach based on the comments :)

Comment: Off-topic: Arial (or Helvetica) text font and Latin Modern math font must be one of the worst ever font combinations.

Comment: @Mico I have no choice but to use Arial as the text font, it is mandated by the report receivers.  I am not sure about other combinations for math font when the main text font is Arial - is that worth a new question?

Comment: Another off-topic comment: To capture the probability `P(M_p \leq 2)`, shouldn't the integration run from `-\infty` to `2` instead of just from `0` to `2`?

Comment: @ @Mico the MolProbity score exists only within [0, inf], it can't go lower then 0, I just realized what you meant, I should put `P(0 \leq Mp \leq 2)` instead, thanks for catching that!

Comment: but why the over-large `\dfrac` rather than a normal `\frac` ??

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the `frac` makes the `\sigma` and other values unreadable without zooming in, I wanted it to be visible to the people reading it without them having to change zoom etc, I thought that would work

Comment: sure, that's why `exp(...)` syntax is better, but essentially your question is  'I forced over-large fonts by using dfrac, how do  I "reduce the font size"' so "don't do that" is the natural answer:-) (but Mico's answer is more helpful)

Comment: @Mico thanks for the feedback on this, I changed the math font to `XITS Math` and it looks so much better with your feedback (I put the `~ 0.834` on the same line to save space, have a page limit): https://imgur.com/a/fvoOpUP (not sure why there is an age warning on this haha)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am having to use `\dfrac` for the exponent fractions as the normal frac is unreadable

No you don't. The output of `e^{-\dfrac{...}{...}}` has no chance at all of looking decent. Instead, do use "exp notation": `\exp\biggl(-\frac{...}{...}\biggr)`. exp notation has been around for decades; do use it from time to time.

And, do insert a linebreak -- and even better two line breaks -- since the formula has no chance at all of fitting on a single line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,
            top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\lipsum[1][1-6]
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mbfitP(M_p \leq 2) 
&= \int_0^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}
   \exp\biggl(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\biggr)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&= \int_0^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(0.479)^2}}
   \exp\biggl(-\frac{(x-1.517)^2}{2(0.479)^2}\biggr)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\approx 0.843
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\lipsum [1][1-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this standard for large exponents with fractions to show it as `exp()`? I (mistakenly it appears) assumed it would be with `frac` instead, I am not too familiar reading maths papers, mainly biochem. Might need to read some to get with the flow of what is typical

Comment: @JamesT - exp notation is indeed an entirely standard notational convention for math material. Oh, and the argument of "exp(...)" doesn't have to be fraction.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I'm going to accept this sooner then probably it should be as a I like your format and it answered my question :)